# command line argument to clipboard

Tags: python

I am learning python and would like verification on a hunch I have about CL args and Python's clipboard. When passing CL args to a script does that arg automatically get added to the clipboard. The code that makes me ask this question is pasted below:

```
import shelve, pyperclip, sys

#mcb.py - saves and loasd pieces of text to the clipboard
#usage: py.exe mcb.py save <keyword> - saves clipboard to keyword
#   py.exe mcb.py list - loads all keywords to clipboard
#   py.exe mcb.py <keyword> -loads keyword to clipboard
mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')
if len(sys.argv)==3 and sys.argv[1].lower()=='save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
if sys.argv[1].lower =='list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])
mcbShelf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Program arguments are not copied to the "clipboard" but can be accessed
 via `sys.argv` (the code above appears to copy the code to the clipboard with pyperclip)